# I access the download folder but I cannot access the files in the download folder on android

Tags: android, file, android-studio, file-exists

I access the download folder but I cannot access the files in the download folder on android. I want to check the present of a file in the download folder. For example, when I want to download a file named example.txt from the internet, I want to check if that file is in the download folder. I looked for many solutions but I couldn't find. Thanks

```
File dir=  new File(Environment.
                getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                        .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/example.pdf");

        if(dir.exists()) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: First, use `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/belge.pdf");`. It is shorter, faster, and more reliable than what you have. Second, you need permissions to access [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) this way. Third, you have no access to this location on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: i added permissions and i tried "File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/belge.pdf");" but it not vorking

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code if using in Android10.

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
```