# Fails to access the `Downloads` folder

Tags: java, android, file, android-storage

I am trying to save a txt file into the Downloads folder in my first abndroid app.

```
public class DisplaySettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private H300sVoipSettings settings;

    Button saveIntoFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_settings);

        this.settings = (H300sVoipSettings) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("H300sVoipSettings");

        this.saveIntoFile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        this.saveIntoFile.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

private String saveFile(){
        Log.d("Η300s","Saving");
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Log.e("H300s","Unable to detect external storage");
            return null;
        }

        DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyMMdd");
        File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        file = new File( file.getAbsolutePath(),"voip_h300s_"+pattern.format(LocalDate.now())+".txt");
        Log.d("H300s",file.toString());
        try {
            Log.d("H300s","Saving");
            this.settings.save(file);
            Log.d("H300s","Saved");
            Log.d("H300s",file.getAbsolutePath());
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("H300s",e.toString());
            Log.e("H300s",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But this piece of code in my function:

```
 this.settings.save(file);
```

Fails to be saved due to lack of permissions. As the following log shows:

```
2021-04-24 14:48:18.498 8208-8208/com.example.vodafone_fu_h300s E/H300s: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
2021-04-24 14:48:18.499 8208-8208/com.example.vodafone_fu_h300s E/H300s: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at pc_magas.vodafone_fu_h300s.screens.DisplaySettingsActivity.saveFile(DisplaySettingsActivity.java:97)
        at pc_magas.vodafone_fu_h300s.screens.DisplaySettingsActivity.onClick(DisplaySettingsActivity.java:120)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25906)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What I want to do is to save a txt file into Downloads Folder and make it accessible to the user via file manager. The class `H300sVoipSettings` has the following:

```
public class H300sVoipSettings implements Serializable
{
    private String username = null;

    private String password = null;

    private String primary_registar =  null;

    private String primary_registar_port = null;

    private String secondary_registar = null;

    private String secondary_registar_port = null;

    private String primary_proxy = null;

    private String primary_proxy_port = null;

    private String secondary_proxy = null;

    private String secondary_proxy_port = null;

    private String sip_domain = null;

    private String sip_number = null;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPrimary_registar() {
        return primary_registar;
    }

    public void setPrimary_registar(String primary_registar) {
        this.primary_registar = primary_registar;
    }

    public String getPrimary_registar_port() {
        return primary_registar_port;
    }

    public void setPrimary_registar_port(String primary_registar_port) {
        this.primary_registar_port = primary_registar_port;
    }

    public String getSecondary_registar() {
        if(secondary_registar == null || secondary_registar.trim().equals("")){
            return null;
        }
        return secondary_registar;
    }

    public void setSecondary_registar(String secondary_registar) {
        this.secondary_registar = secondary_registar;
    }

    public String getSecondary_registar_port() {
        return secondary_registar_port;
    }

    public void setSecondary_registar_port(String secondary_registar_port) {
        this.secondary_registar_port = secondary_registar_port;
    }

    public String getPrimary_proxy() {
        return primary_proxy;
    }

    public void setPrimary_proxy(String primary_proxy) {
        this.primary_proxy = primary_proxy;
    }

    public String getPrimary_proxy_port() {
        return primary_proxy_port;
    }

    public void setPrimary_proxy_port(String primary_proxy_port) {
        this.primary_proxy_port = primary_proxy_port;
    }

    public String getSecondary_proxy() {
        return secondary_proxy;
    }

    public void setSecondary_proxy(String secondary_proxy) {
        this.secondary_proxy = secondary_proxy;
    }

    public String getSecondary_proxy_port() {
        return secondary_proxy_port;
    }

    public void setSecondary_proxy_port(String secondary_proxy_port) {
        this.secondary_proxy_port = secondary_proxy_port;
    }

    public String getSip_domain() {
        return sip_domain;
    }

    public void setSip_domain(String sip_domain) {
        this.sip_domain = sip_domain;
    }

    public String getSip_number() {
        return sip_number;
    }

    public void setSip_number(String sip_number) {
        this.sip_number = sip_number;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public static H300sVoipSettings createFromJson(String jsonString) throws IllegalArgumentException, JSONException {
        if(jsonString == null || jsonString.trim().equals("")){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("JsonString Should not be empty");
        }

        JSONArray settingsJson = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        H300sVoipSettings settings = new H300sVoipSettings();

        for (int i = 0; i < settingsJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = settingsJson.getJSONObject(i);
            if(item.getString("type").equals("provider")){
                settings.setPrimary_registar(item.getString("primary_registrar"));
                settings.setPrimary_registar_port(item.getString("primary_registrar_port"));
                settings.setPrimary_proxy(item.getString("primary_proxy"));
                settings.setPrimary_proxy_port(item.getString("primary_proxy_port"));
                settings.setSip_domain(item.getString("sip_domain"));
                String secondary_proxy = item.getString("secondary_proxy");
                if(secondary_proxy != null && !secondary_proxy.trim().equals("")){
                    settings.setSecondary_proxy(secondary_proxy.trim());
                }
                settings.setSecondary_proxy_port(item.getString("secondary_proxy_port"));
                settings.setSecondary_registar(item.getString("secondary_registrar"));
                settings.setSecondary_registar_port(item.getString("secondary_registrar_port"));
            } else if(item.getString("type").equals("number")){
                settings.setSip_number(item.getString("sip_number"));
                settings.setUsername(item.getString("username"));
                settings.setPassword(item.getString("password"));
            }
        }

        return settings;
    }

    public boolean equals(H300sVoipSettings other){

        boolean truth =  other.getPassword().equals(this.getPassword()) &&
               other.getUsername().equals(this.getUsername()) &&
               other.getSip_number().equals(this.getSip_number()) &&
               other.getSip_domain().equals(this.getSip_domain()) &&
               other.getPrimary_proxy().equals(this.getPrimary_proxy()) &&
               other.getPrimary_proxy_port().equals(this.getPrimary_proxy_port()) &&
               other.getPrimary_registar().equals(this.getPrimary_registar()) &&
               other.getPrimary_registar_port().equals(this.getPrimary_registar_port()) &&
               other.getSecondary_proxy_port().equals(this.getSecondary_proxy_port()) &&
               other.getSecondary_registar_port().equals(this.getSecondary_registar_port());


        truth = truth && ((other.getSecondary_proxy() == null && this.getSecondary_proxy() == null) || (other.getSecondary_proxy().equals(this.getSecondary_proxy())));
        truth = truth &&
                (
                        (other.getSecondary_registar() == null && this.getSecondary_registar() == null) ||
                                (
                                        other.getSecondary_registar().equals(this.getSecondary_registar())
                                )
                );
        return truth;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();

            txt.append("Phone Number: ");
            txt.append(this.getSip_number());
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Username: ");
            txt.append(this.getUsername());
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Password: ");
            txt.append(this.getPassword());
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Sip Domain: ");
            txt.append(this.getSip_domain());
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Primary proxy: ");
            txt.append(this.getPrimary_proxy());
            txt.append(" Port: ");
            txt.append(this.getPrimary_proxy_port());
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Secondary proxy: ");
            String secondary_proxy = this.getSecondary_proxy();
            secondary_proxy = (secondary_proxy == null || !secondary_proxy.trim().equals(""))?"N/A":secondary_proxy;
            txt.append(secondary_proxy);
            txt.append(" Port: ");
            String secondaryProxyPort = this.getSecondary_proxy_port();
            secondaryProxyPort=(secondaryProxyPort == null || !secondaryProxyPort.trim().equals(""))?"N/A":secondaryProxyPort;
            txt.append(secondaryProxyPort);
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Primary Registar: ");
            String primaryRegistar = this.getPrimary_registar();
            txt.append(primaryRegistar);
            txt.append(" Port: ");
            String primaryRegistarPort = this.getPrimary_registar_port();
            txt.append(primaryRegistarPort);
            txt.append("\n");

            txt.append("Secondary Registar: ");
            String secondary_registar = this.getSecondary_registar();
            secondary_registar = (secondary_registar == null || !secondary_registar.trim().equals(""))?"N/A":secondary_registar;
            txt.append(secondary_registar);
            txt.append(" Port: ");
            String secondaryRegistarPort = this.getSecondary_registar();
            secondaryRegistarPort=(secondaryRegistarPort == null || !secondaryRegistarPort.trim().equals(""))?"N/A":secondaryRegistarPort;
            txt.append(secondaryRegistarPort);
            txt.append("\n");

        return txt.toString();
    }

    public void save(File file) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        out.println("********");
        out.print("Exported Date: ");
        out.println(new Date().toString());
        out.println("********");
        out.print(this.toString());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And is used for data serialization. The application has the following in Android Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Furthermore I have looked upon these answers whith no result whatsoever:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748149/4706711

So do you have any idea how I can access the donwloads folder?

Comment: You do it all right seems. But that code just does not work anymore on an Android 10 device.

Comment: `Log.d("H300s",file.toString());` Well... What is logged? And you better log file.getAbsolutePath().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite having the permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You should also prompt the user to accept these requests as well. In order to achieve this the `onCLick` function should be:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("H300s","Permission Accepted");
            saveFile();
        } else {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
        }
    }
```

Where the `requestPermissionLauncher` is initialized into the `onCreate` like this:

```
        requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
            Log.d("H300s","Permissions Callback");

            if (isGranted) {
                Log.d("H300s","Permission Accepted 2");
                saveFile();
            } else {
                permissionSaveDenied();
            }
        });
```

Furthermore, ensure that at `build.gradle` you should place the following:

```
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0'
```

In order for the `ActivityResultContracts` to work.

## Bonus Tip

You can skip declaring the need for this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Because application gonna request the user to provide it nevertheless.